# mySQL license location on Redhat

Tags: mysql, redhat, licensing

We were looking fo rlicense information for mySQL that came installed on a server we purchased through dell that runs RHEL.

Via our rep at Dell we were given the following link:

http://www.redhat.com/licenses/rhel_rha_eula.html

We are specifically interested in the following:
"the license agreement for each software component is located in the software component's source code and permits User to run, copy, modify, and redistribute (subject to certain obligations in some cases) the software component, in both source code and binary code forms."

Does anyone know of or where such a file would be for mySQL on our server?

Comment: Have you considered visiting the MySQl web site for information about their product?

Comment: I have, but we were told to look on the serevr from our rep so that where I wanted to start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL is licensed under the GPL. A copy of which can be found here: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.txt

specifically on your server it would be: `/usr/share/doc/mysql-<mysql_version>/COPYING`

Answer (score 1):

If you paid for an enterprise version of MySQL, Dell should have provided a document with the license information, "serial number". The enterprise version is a different binary from the GPL version. MySQL is dual licensed, so it depends on what you bought from Dell.

Answer (score -4):

With RHEL you get mysql server rpm which dont require any license to install that is bundle with with RHEL

Comment: -1 it is still licensed, just under the GPL